# Rails: List by a column in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table called **imgs** with **album_id** column referencing **albums** table. How can I list images by album_id? Like this:

```
<ul>
    <p>Album1</p>
    <li>Image1 of Album1</li>
    <li>Image2 of Album1</li>
    <li>Image3 of Album1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <p>Album2</p>
    <li>Image1 of Album2</li>
    <li>Image2 of Album2</li>
    <li>Image3 of Album2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by is your friend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
<% grouped_images = @images.group_by(&:album) %>

<% grouped_images.each do |album, images| %>

  <ul>
    <p><%= album.name %></p>

    <% images.each do |image| %>
      <li><%= image.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

<% end %>
```

This code will group your `@images` by their album.

I used a short version of the group_by, which usually need a block, long version:

```
grouped_images = @images.group_by { |image| image.album }
# is exactly the same as
grouped_images = @images.group_by(&:album)
```

Comment: It not work. I get the error undefined method `grouped_images' for #<#<Class:0x007fbe968f7828>:0x007fbe74fb7e50>

Comment: Arf, my bad, I forgot the `.each` ... Answer updated with the fix @marcodamaceno

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<% @albums.each do |album| %>
<ul>
    <p><%= album.name %></p>
    <% album.imgs.each do |img| %>
      <li><%= image_tag img.image %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```